# How to convert unicode escape code to character in Objective C (on iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, unicode

I have a string that contains unicode escape codes, eg. @"D\u017cem" (\u017c is code for ż). I would like to convert that string to the one containg actual characters. In the example that would be @"Dżem".

Is there any method in SDK or library that can do such replacement AND work on iPhone?

(Obviously I can do the replacement myself, changing characters one by one, but it is rather cumbersome)

Comment: Why do you like to convert them ? Don't they work just fine ? `NSLog(@"%@", @"D\u017cem");` yields `Dżem` in a quick test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to start using `NSLocalizedString()`

http://www.pushplay.net/2009/08/developing-localized-iphone-applications/

[http://developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Articles/InternatAndLocaliz.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000277-SW1)

Comment: The problem is I don't have that string under control, I am getting JSON file from the internet, store it as a NSString, which, in turn is parsed by JSON parser that blows on unicode codes.

Comment: I believe that part of the conversation is/should be done by your json framework. What does ie `[[jsonString 
JSONValue] objectForKey:@"name"]` give you?

Comment: Tt works ok, since the problem was elsewhere, sometimes JSON was not properly formed. Thanks for suggestion and help

Answer (score 2):

[According to Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000943-SW2),

> It is *not* safe is to include high-bit characters in your source code

Note that the "universal character name" `\u017c` is replaced at compile time with an implementation-defined value which in practice is the UTF8 representation, so the end result is the same as you would get if you (correctly) did the replacement you are talking about. If you're having a problem with some other source-processing tool, you might be better served by teaching that tool to recognize C99 universal character names.